# Can we simplify the expression while finding domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Equation A------------>    $y=x$  , It has domain of Real Numbers.

Equation B------------>    $y=\frac{1}{(1/x)}$,  It has domain of $R-${$0$}.

Context: I solved $y=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{ \frac{x-1}{x-2}}    }$ and calculated domain $(- \infty ,1) \cup(2,\infty).$ I wonder the domain will change if the expression is simplified i.e.(x-2) taken to numerator, so the question is can we simplify the given expression first and then find the domain or we are not allowed to alter the expression in question while finding the domain?

Graph from wolfram for $y=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{ \frac{x-1}{x-2}}    }$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3Dsqrt%281%2F%28%28x-1%29%2F%28x-2%29%29%29

Graph from wolfram for $ y=\sqrt{ \frac{x-2}{x-1}}$
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%28x-2%29%2F%28x-1%29%29

Comment: Scroll down to see the [domain](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3D1%2F%28%28x-1%29%2F%28x-2%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29) See now.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cpu5lfnlrr

Comment: You may look at the [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3D1%2F%28%28x-1%29%2F%28x-2%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29)

Comment: There is change of domain as seen in result of wolfram alpha.

Comment: You can't actually see the point $x=2$ in the graph.

Comment: We can see x=2 point in https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%28x-2%29%2F%28x-1%29%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. When you study a function defined as follows:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g(x)}}$$
you have first to study when the denominator is defined or in other words when:
$$g(x)\neq 0$$
and then when the square root is defined:
$$g(x)\geq0$$
At this point, you can bind the two conditions into a system and find the domain of $f(x)$.

> Once you have found the domain, you can rearrange, but the domain doesn't change.

For example the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{ \frac{x-2}{x-1}}$ is $x<1 \vee x\geq 2$ and this $f(x)$ can be obtained by $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$. If you are given $g(x)$ you can notice that the domain of $g(x)$ doesn't include $x=2$ which is a part of the domain of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with previous answer, I want to add to it that in mathematics “1/“ means “the reciprocal of”.

The number that needs to be reciprocated must exist, otherwise 1/ makes no sense.

Therefore, we start with the number and apply restrictions that makes the number possible.

Then we reciprocate and apply restrictions that make the operation possible, since not all numbers can be reciprocated.

Then if need be, we square root- as in your example and again limit the domain of the variable as to make the operation possible.